# Image not randomising in array?

Tags: javascript, html

```
function doSingle()
{
    var luck= ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'],
    var imagesArray = ["thumbs/lr/lrgokublack.png", "thumbs/lr/lrtrunks.png", "thumbs/lr/lrgohan.png", "thumbs/lr/lrmajinvegeta.png"];
    var ssrArray = ["thumbs/ssr/beerus1.png", "thumbs/ssr/broly1.png"];
    lucknumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * luck.length));

    if (lucknumber < 8) {
        function displayImage() {
        var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * ssrArray.length);
        window.canvas.src = ssrArray[num];
}
    } else {
        function displayImage() {
        var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * imagesArray.length);
        window.canvas.src = imagesArray[num];
        }
}
}
```

This code will not work, but I think it's correct? I'm pretty sure I called the `doSingle` too in my html code;

```
<head>
<p id="soup"></p>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="formalign.css">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="trinit5.js"></script>
      <input onclick="doSingle();" id="image" type="image" alt="Summon" src="ssbutton1.png" width="25%"/> 
      <img id="canvas"></img>
      <div class="element"></div>

</head>
```

My intentions are to randomise the luck, and depending  on that luck, a certain number will give you an **SR** or a **SSR** (rarities) Also, a few people said this html code is wrong, but it works for me, and won't work when I change it, so I'll leave it as it is :D Thanks in advance!

EDIT: In inspect element, is says doSingle() is not defined????

Comment: lucknumber will be an integer from 0 to 9, as it doesn't reference an element in the luck array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have two issues:**

You're declaring variables inline, so you don't need multiple usages of keyword `var`

```
var luck= ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'],
   var imagesArray = ["thumbs/lr/lrgokublack.
   ^
```

You're not calling the function `displayImage`, you just declared it.  So, call it.

```
function displayImage() {
^
```

**This code snippet has those fixes:**

```js
function doSingle() {
  var luck = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'],
    imagesArray = ["thumbs/lr/lrgokublack.png", "thumbs/lr/lrtrunks.png", "thumbs/lr/lrgohan.png", "thumbs/lr/lrmajinvegeta.png"];
  var ssrArray = ["thumbs/ssr/beerus1.png", "thumbs/ssr/broly1.png"];
  lucknumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * luck.length));

  if (lucknumber < 8) {
    function displayImage() {
      var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * ssrArray.length);
      window.canvas.src = ssrArray[num];
    }

    displayImage();
  } else {
    function displayImage() {
      var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * imagesArray.length);
      window.canvas.src = imagesArray[num];
    };

    displayImage();
  }
}

doSingle();
```

```html
<p id="soup"></p>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="formalign.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="trinit5.js"></script>
<input onclick="doSingle();" id="image" type="image" alt="Summon" src="ssbutton1.png" width="25%" />
<img id="canvas"></img>
<div class="element"></div>
```